# Replace odd lines reading from stdin with sed

Tags: bash, sed

As preparation for a test, a friend and me decided to play around a bit with sed. Yet, we noticed some odd / unusual behaviour when trying to perform substitions on odd lines.

It seems like all sed commands but the p command don't work when working with input from stdin

Example: https://gyazo.com/1c8d7fcb2ebd992849704b80c8ec6ab9

[image: Direct image]

```
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -n '1~2p' # Works fine / as expected
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -n '1~2s/./&&/g' # Doesn't give output. The specific substitution is just a test.
echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -n '1~2d' # Once again no output. (I'm aware that this is equal to only printing the even lines.)
```

Is there a reason to this behaviour?

We did figure it out in the meantime though, seems like

```
sed 'N;s/./&&/g'
```

would indeed work.

Although the question remains: What if I only want to perform the substitution on the 50th line? I don't want to have to write N;N;N; ... 50 times before applying the substitution.

Comment: The right tool for the job (IMHO) would not be `sed` but `awk` if you're trying to only process some deterministic selection of lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. The problem you are facing is that you are using `-n` (*suppress automatic printing of pattern space*) but then you don't tell `sed` to print lines in any way.

To prevent this, you can either supress the `-n` and handle the conditions differently or add a `-p` to trigger the print.

See the cases:

`sed -n '1~2d'` is not printing anything because you are using `-n` to stop printing, so you need to tell `sed` "hey, print something".

So you can either just say remove odd lines:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed '1~2d'
2
4
```

or add a `p` after deleting:

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -n '1~2d;p'
2
4
```

---

The same applies to the second command: if you add a `p` after the substitution, it works!

```
$ echo -e "1\n2\n3\n4\n5" | sed -n '1~2s/./&&/gp'
11
33
55
```

---

> Although the question remains: What if I only want to perform the
>   substitution on the 50th line? I don't want to have to write N;N;N;
>   ... 50 times before applying the substitution.

For this I would use `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==50 {things...}' file
```

This uses the variable `NR`, number of record, that keeps track of the line number.

Answer (score 0):

> What if I only want to perform the substitution on the 50th line?

You may want to read sed man page about the **address** part.

check this `seq 10|sed '7s/.*/-/'`.

btw, your `N;N;...50times` is wrong. this will do substitution on first 50 lines, instead of on 50th line. You can figure it out by some test.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different answer, but still works on OSX (e.g. edit 4th line of the original file):

```
seq 1 8  | sed -e '1d;4s/./&&/g;n;d'
```

Or edit all even lines:

```
seq 1 8  | sed -e '1d;s/./&&/g;n;d'
```

Or edit all odd lines (not asked, but just in case someone will find this useful in the future):

```
seq 1 8  | sed -e 's/./&&/g;n;d'
```

Useful tips for sed:
`1d` - deletes the first line
`n` - replaces the line with the next line
`d` - deletes the next line and starts the cycle again (replace and delete).